# AJAX async:false blocking progress dialog in non-Mozilla browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax

As a band-aid fix to potential out-of-order AJAX call completion, my shopping cart provider recently stuck "async:false" into the cart calculation code.  This had the side effect of preventing a jquery progress dialog from displaying on non-Mozilla browsers.  So those users sit there with an unresponsive page thinking something is broken, while shipping and sales tax is being calculated.

Here is what they told me about this:

> "Ajax calls in the other browsers block the javascript ui events.
>   Firefox allows the ui dialog to display even though it has been
>   deferred slightly and the ajax starts"

I could refactor their code and chain the AJAX calls but I really don't want to do that much surgery on their code.

Is there any other way to get this to work?

Comment: *"shopping cart provider recently stuck "async:false" into the cart calculation code"* ? Tell them the internet thinks it's a bug. *Never* do synchronous AJAX calls.

Comment: I've already beat them up enough about this, they felt like they had to rush this 'fix' out to prevent the cart from generating a total before shipping and tax were latched.  I'm stuck at this point and need to figure out my own way to fix this, or regress to an older version of the cart which I do not want to do for other reasons.

Comment: There's nothing you can do against that. That's what synchronous XHR does: it blocks the UI. Tell them to learn how to use promises if they want to make sure the order of their XHR requests is respected.

Comment: OK.  What I also don't understand is that the jquery dialog calls are modal -- which blocks the UI as well, so if they were putting up a dialog at each step of cart calculation why were they worried about AJAX completing out-of-order?  Maybe I just go into their code and set async:true and don't worry about it (?)

Comment: jQuery dialog doesn't *actually* block the UI. It just... covers it. With more UI.

Comment: Sigh.  OK guys thanks, I figured I'd end up here but was hoping there would be some alternative.  Back to begging the cart developer to do the right thing...

Answer (score 0):

Setting async to to false definitely caused this problem.  I ran into the same problem just the other day.  The only way to have animation and synchronous requests is to insert pauses using `window.setTimeout()`.  This isn't ideal though since it will add a obligatory delay in execution.  Also, you might see the animation stop and start as synchronous requests are run.

If you want to get the code to work asynchronously I suggest something like this:

```
$("#form").submit( function (event) {
    $("#dataToIterateThru").each( function (i, val) {
        event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://mytargeturl.com/?parameter=' + val,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html',
                context: $("<span>", {id: 'ajax-'+i}).appendTo($("#output")),
                success: function (data) {
                    $(this).replaceWith(data.value);
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

If you didn't catch that, the `context` property makes a placeholder for the callback function to refer to later (using `$(this)`).  You could also just use a sequence number (e.g. 1,2,3,4) for the `context` and send the data along with the number to a "processing" function.  Every time the function is called it will process the data it has in order, stopping when a sequence number is missing.  Interestingly that's almost the same method TCP uses for out-of-order packets.